# Is there any number with $2017$ divisors whose sum of digits is $2017$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request

> Is there any number with $2017$ divisors whose sum of digits is $2017$?

We know that $2017$ is prime and any number satisfying the required condition is of the form $p^{2016}$, where $p$ is a prime number. From here I couldn't make any progress.

Any help or reference would be appreciated.

Comment: From my observations from a computer program, the answer is negative.  The least case $2^{2016}$ has sum of digits $2656$, and the sum of digits increases (most of the time, not always) so quickly that the number becomes larger than $10000$ when $p \ge 13$.

Comment: I've written [a program in Julia](https://gist.github.com/VincentTam/18f90a605447ead43963baef57bd5103) to see this.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is known to be impossible.  However there are similar questions where it's easy to show non-existence: there are no numbers with $2011$ divisors whose sum of digits is $2011$.  I wonder if this question was adapted from an earlier year :).

Answer (score 8):

**Heuristic argument**

You have correctly identified that such a number must be of the form $p^{2016}$, where $p$ is a prime.

From Wolfram, $$\begin{array}{c|c}\text{number}&2^{2016}&3^{2016}&5^{2016}&7^{2016}&11^{2016}&13^{2016}&17^{2016}&19^{2016}\\\hline\text{sum of digits}&2656&4293&6211&7552&9559&10126&11539&11584\end{array}$$
Hence we would not expect any number to have such properties; otherwise at least [$2746-2017=729$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+digits+of+5%5E2016) digits have to be $0$ for the next possible number $23^{2016}$ (and every other digit must be $1$), which is extremely unlikely.